# Date formatting an ISO datetime into a readable formant

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt, format

I'm trying to process the ISO date value below to a more readable format using XML Version 1.0.

```
<ValueString>2022-11-29T19:21:32.449Z</ValueString>
```

```
<xsl:value-of select="date:formatDate(/bml:Value/bml:ValueString,'yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss z')" />
```

The result I get is this:

```
 2022.11.28 11:00:00 GMT
```

It seems like the 'yyy.MM.dd HH.mm.ss z' is failing and not processing the Hour, minute, seconds correctly. I've tried a handful of options but I'm not entirely sure what the issue is. Anyone have any ideas of how to process this value?

Thank you

Comment: Well, which XSLT 1.0 processor exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In your place I would do simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(ValueString, 1, 19), '-T', '. ')"/>
```

---

If you want to include a time zone designation, then try something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(ValueString, 1, 19), '-T', '. ')"/>
<xsl:text> GMT</xsl:text>
<xsl:if test="not(contains(ValueString, 'Z'))">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(ValueString, string-length(ValueString) - 5)"/>
</xsl:if>
```

---

Note that fractional seconds will be truncated, not rounded to the nearest second.

Comment: This seems to be working, how can I add in the 'Z' to get the GMT +1:00 or GMT+2:00 to show up?

Comment: You cannot. If you want to pass the existing timezone designation to the result, you need to extract it and append it to the output above. If you want to modify it, then you need to tell us what would be the rules for such modification.